# Is it possible to lazy load complex types from a WCF Data Service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have DbContext subclass

```
ReportingContext : DbContext
```

As I'm doing simple CRUD I then created a WCF Data service to expose my DbSet...

```
public class ReportService : DataService<ReportingContext>
```

I have been able to use the ReportingContext directly to do 'table splitting'. Basically use 2 entities (ReportLayout and ReportLayoutData) which both use a single table. I was able to configure this using the fluent API. Everything worked fine in Unit tests as I was able to return ReportLayouts and only load ReportLayoutData when they were accessed.

My problems started when I tried to do this through a WCF Data Service, OData version 5.6 - using the DataServiceContext class. Returning ReportLayouts work fine, but trying to **lazy load** the dependent data has not been possible so far. I have tried different things:

- Calling Include via a service method actually worked when I debugged the service directly and checked the generated sql - 2 separate queries as for the unit test. However, the service simply did not include the ReportLayoutData property in its returned properties when viewed in the browser and I got client side errors relating to the missing property.

  ```
  [WebGet]
  public IQueryable<ReportLayout> GetReportsByID(string ids)
  {
      var ints = GetInts(ids);
      return  CurrentDataSource.Reports.Include("LayoutData").Where(x =>  ints.Contains(x.ReportLayoutID)).AsQueryable();
  }

  private static int[] GetInts(string ids)
  {
      return ids.Split(",".ToCharArray()).Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToArray();
  }
  ```
- I tried to use DataServiceContext.Expand - $expand - and this failed with various
  errors as I tried slighly different arguments
- I tried calling Execute, various problems
- I turned the ReportLayoutData property into an IQueryable even though it is a 1-1 relationship and now it says ReportLayoutData is not a property of ReportLayout when running the EF specific unit test that previously worked fine.

My question: is it possible to Lazy Load via a WCF Data service in this manner or should I just expose 2 collections and resolve the results into a single object on the client?  If it is possible I would just like to see the basic pattern - a couple of related entities, fluent API declarations and the DataService code. Thanks for any help.

**EDIT**

I am currently being plagued by the error:

***A property with name 'LayoutData' on type 'ReportLayout' has kind 'Structural', but it is expected to be of kind 'Navigation'.***

Although there is no problem retrieving the data in the browser: ReportService.svc/Reports()?$expand=LayoutData

partial stack trace:

Microsoft.Data.OData.ReaderValidationUtils.ValidateNavigationPropertyDefined(String propertyName, IEdmEntityType owningEntityType, ODataMessageReaderSettings messageReaderSettings) 
at
Microsoft.Data.OData.Atom.ODataAtomEntryAndFeedDeserializer.TryReadNavigationLinkInEntry(IODataAtomReaderEntryState entryState, String linkRelation, String linkHRef)

I was able to remove the above error by not exposing 2 dbSets through the service. Will consider a service operation to return what I need from EF, shame it isn't so elegant.

Comment: Firstly, no there is no off the shelf method for implementing lazy loading. It is of course possible. However I would advise highly against it. A round trip with OData is typically on the order of a few hundred ms. Lazy loading is by nature a synchronous pattern. In a typical application, a user WILL notice unresponsiveness of a few hundred ms. If we are tight looping, forget UX completely. You can take a look at `DataServiceContext.LoadProperty`, but I would advise you use the async calls when possible.

Comment: @Aron Thanks for this - I did try LoadProperty and if I recall correctly it gave me an error message saying it only works for collections. My ReportLayout at the time only expose a single *virtual ReportLayoutData* object at the time. I could try that again, if only for the satisfaction of seeing it work. I think you are right about UX but don't see an issue as it will be only a single request and this call can be made asynchronous.

Comment: @Aron What a pain, if I make my ReportLayout.LayoutData a collection I get a missing property exception when trying to instantiate the service. If I try to use LoadProperty with ReportLayout just having a single object property I get - The closed type Framework.Reports.ReportLayout does not have a corresponding ReportLayout/LayoutData settable property. I've had this error before and think it might be time for a coffee and forget about lazy loading via WCF.

Comment: umm...is there a `set` on `Report.LayoutData`?

Comment: @Aron Yes - public virtual ReportLayoutData LayoutData { get; set; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end my solution was to split the table so as to create a navigation property exposed as an ICollection

I was able to implement queries such as *Reports/ReportService.svc/Reports(1) $expand=LayoutData* as a result (AddQueryOption("$expand", "LayoutData") and wrote a service method to do this for multiples.

```
    [WebGet]
    public IQueryable<ReportLayout> GetReportsByID(string ids)
```

I only exposed a single Dbset via the service - the children are not accessible directly.

Client side updates to the dependent entities can be achieved using the DataServiceContext methods:

```
AddObject, AddLink
AttachTo, UpdateObject, AttachLink //UpdateObject on the child ensures the entity state changes to modified (see DataServiceContext.Entites collection).
```

In retrospect I probably did not need to split the table but do not have time to play with this.